# Meteor - Find a document from collection via Mongo ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, meteor

If you create a Mongo document directly inside Mongo and want to access this same document via Meteor, what is the best way to accomplish this task?

I am getting undefined result when I attempt to access.

If you create a new document from Meteor it does not prefix the id with ObjectId("").

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I want to simply find exact document by exact ObjectId.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use `Meteor.Collection.ObjectID`:

```
var oid = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID("a86ce44f9a46b99bca1be7a9");
var doc = SomeCollection.findOne(oid);
```

See the [options for how unique IDs in collections are generated](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection). However, it's general practice in Meteor to use the string approach because clients can then generate unique IDs reliably.

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. I did not realize that I needed to create a new local collection to push the Mongo ObjectID into before I can lookup against other collections.

Comment: @jremi not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: I did not realize that I needed to create a new variable to associate the ObjectID before passing to the find call. I was trying to pass the ObjectId directly into the findOne and was having issues. Now things are working.

Comment: @jremi: you don't need a variable, you can just pass it as `SomeCollection.findOne(new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID("a86ce44f9a46b99bca1be7a9"));`. The key here is to create `Meteor.Collection.ObjectID` object.